# WP исключить стиль из футера

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть код для подключения стилей и скриптов из header в footer для оптимизации.

```
    function footer_enqueue_scripts(){
        remove_action('wp_head','wp_print_scripts');
        remove_action('wp_head','wp_print_head_scripts',9);
        remove_action('wp_head','wp_enqueue_scripts',1);
        add_action('wp_footer','wp_print_scripts',5);
        add_action('wp_footer','wp_enqueue_scripts',5);
        add_action('wp_footer','wp_print_head_scripts',5);
    }
    add_action('after_setup_theme','footer_enqueue_scripts');
```

Подскажите, как можно исключить из этого переноса какой-то один стиль, зарегистрированный с помощью `wp_enqueue_style("dfd_header_builder_front", $path);`
т.е. чтобы не все стили перенеслись в футер.
Можно ли как-то сформировать массив, и удалить из него один стиль, чтобы он остался в header?

**P.S.**

```
class WPBakeryShortCode_Dfd_User_Form extends WPBakeryShortCode {

    public function __construct($settings) {
        wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-datepicker");
        wp_enqueue_style("dfd_datepicker", DFD_EXTENSIONS_PLUGIN_URL . "vc_custom/user_form/assets/css/datepicker/datepicker.min.css");
```

**functions.php**

```
function dequeue_dfd() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'dfd_datepicker' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_dfd', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Comment: Вопрос понятен, кроме этого: `Можно ли как-то сформировать массив`

Comment: @KAGG Design, имеется ввиду `Название скрипта (рабочее название). Строка в нижнем регистре.`, т.е. первый аргумент в `wp_enqueue_script`, wp_enqueue_script('newscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js'); Хорошо, если без этого массива названий, как можно тогда один стиль оставить в `header`, используя вышеприведённый код `add_action('after_setup_theme','footer_enqueue_scripts');`?

Comment: или первый аргумент в `wp_enqueue_style` `Название файла стилей (идентификатор)`, т.е. это я про массив таких названий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы исключить только один стиль, вам нужен следующий код:

```
function dequeue_dfd() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'dfd_header_builder_front' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_dfd', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Он выполняется по событию `wp_enqueue_scripts`, с самым низким приоритетом, гарантированно после всех остальных функций по этому событию. Это гарантирует, что стиль `dfd_header_builder_front` уже добавлен в очередь (иначе невозможно его удалить из очереди). Функция в примере удаляет требуемый стиль.

Comment: а подскажите, ваш код работает, но не для всех стилей, файл datepicker.min.css всё-равно подключается. из-за чего это может быть? прикрепил код в вопрос

Comment: В вопросе нет кода с тим файлом. Но общее правило таково: скрипт/стиль отменять надо по handle (первый аргумент в wp_enqueue_script()/wp_enqueue_style()